# Stim and pickle/dill incompatibility

Tags: stim

I have been using pickle (and also tried dill) to save and load Clifford gates coming from the Stim library. The following code:
`cliff_list = dill.load(filename)`
gives the error
`ImportError: generic_type: type "CompiledDemSampler" is already registered!`.

The code is running fine on my laptop but not on a remote computer, where this error occurs. I am using other methods from Stim in the script where I try to load the above file. How should I try to fix this?

Comment: Please report this as a bug at https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues and provide code that reproduces the issue so I can fix it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking into this!